# Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have the following docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
  containerA:
    healthcheck:
      test: "/build/docheck"
      interval: "10s"
    hostname: "containerA"
    container_name: "containerA"
    build:
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile-5.6"
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"
version: "2.1"
```

When I try the following command: **docker-compose up**

it fails due to:

*ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a version of "2" (or "2.0") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/*

I have the following setting:

```
$> docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown

$> docker --version
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

$> uname -r
4.9.0-4-amd64

$> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch)
Release:    9.3
Codename:   stretch
```

I need to use version 2.1 because I am using the healthcheck. Any ideas why this is complaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the link to details about versions, you'll find:

> Version 2.1
>
> An upgrade of version 2 that introduces new parameters only available
>   with Docker Engine version 1.12.0+. Version 2.1 files are supported by
>   Compose 1.9.0+.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-21

You'll need to upgrade your docker-compose install to support the 2.1 file version. https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Answer (score 4):

Compose files Version 2.1 are supported by **Docker Compose version 1.9.0+**. And you have `docker-compose` version 1.8.0. To upgrade `docker-compose` you can run following commands:

If installed via `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-compose
```

If installed via `curl`:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

If installed via `pip`:

```
pip uninstall docker-compose
```

Then *find the newest version* [on the release page at GitHub](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) or by curling the API and extracting the version from the response using grep:

```
VERSION=$(curl --silent https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | grep -Po '"tag_name": "\K.*\d')
```

Finally, download to your $PATH-accessible location and set permissions:

```
DESTINATION=/usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${VERSION}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o $DESTINATION
sudo chmod 755 $DESTINATION
```

Answer (score 3):

adding this because i ran into the same error on Ubuntu.

For me, it had nothing to do with my `Compose` version despite what the error message says; i just had to run with `sudo`. so

`sudo docker-compose up`

Comment: Worked for me as well. I can't understand why... :S

Comment: This is actually bad if you're not in a production environment because it will obligate you to use `sudo` all the time. I believe the best way is uninstall the current docker-compose and install the stable version from the docker official source. Follow the answer of Anshita Singh in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when I was trying the command `docker-compose up` with the docker compose version 3. Then I run the command to check the docker version `docker version`, which result the below output.

```
PS C:\SVenu\M4Movie\Api\Api> docker version
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:12:48 2018
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm
```

So my version is 18.03, which is the latest one for now. So I moved to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix) to check the compose file version which supports this engine. Then changed my docker compose version to 3.6.

`version: '3.6'`

Everything was working fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Installation of a **new version** of *Docker Compose* helped me to fix this error. See [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose).

Comment: I ran `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose` and it worked.